# Rewording of a question regarding actions.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Can someone re-word the following question in to more basic terms:

'Let $X$ be a finite set. A powerset $P(X)$ of $X$ is the set of all subsets of $X$. Define $\lambda$ as follows $\forall g \in Sym(X)$ and $\forall \{x_1, ..., x_n\} \in P(X)$:

$$\lambda(g)\{x_1,...,x_n\} = \{gx_1,...,gx_n\}$$
Prove that $\lambda$ is an action of $Sym(X)$ on $P(X)$.'

Do I simply have to show:

1. $\lambda(e_{Sym(X)})x = x$  for all $x \in X$.

2.$\lambda(fg)x = \lambda(f)(\lambda(g)x)$ for all $f,g, \in Sym(X)$ and for all $x \in X$.

Or is there more to the question?

Any help would be greatly appreciated in helping me understand the question a little bit more.

Comment: $\lambda(g)x$ is not defined for $x\in X$, but $\lambda(g)A$ is defined for $A\in P(X)$. Hence 1, 2 should be rewritten replacing $x$ with an element of $P(X)$.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer just this part of the question

> Can someone re-word the following question in to more basic terms

If you have a way to permute the elements of a finite set $X$ then there is a natural way to permute subsets of $X$ - just permute what they contain.

You are asked to fill in the formal argument that shows that natural definition really works.

I haven't read your formal argument but I think there's a problem. The assertions should be about "all $A \in P(X)$", not "all $x \in X$".